# Update table column when the user clicks item in a listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to update a table when the user clicks an item in the listview by setting an onclicklistener here is my code

```
view_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {

         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3)
    {
             String click = (addArrrayList.get(arg2).toString());
            shoppingListDB.rawQuery("UPDATE ITEMS SET FOUND = 'YES' WHERE ITEM_NAME ="+ "'" +click+"'", null);

    }

    });
```

Comment: then what is your problem?

Comment: @Simple Plan When i click the item, the table doesn't update

Comment: go with `DB.update()`

Comment: did you have any focusable widget on list item? did onItem called after click? check with debug or log

Comment: @shayanpourvatan yes i have requestfocus widget.

Comment: add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on parent of list item in xml file

Comment: @shayanpourvatan i did doesn't work

Comment: did you try `convertView.onClickListener()` in `getView()` method on adapter class?

Comment: Write a simple line `System.out.println ( "ok" );` in your `onItemClick()` and check if that method executes or not. Also you forgot to `Override` the method.

Comment: @SimplePlan how do i implement that?

Comment: @shayanpourvatan i have inserted a toast after the update statement and it works fine, i don't why it doesn't update the table.

Comment: check your query, maybe you don't have any row that `ITEM_NAME = click"`

Comment: The items in the listview are from the table so it does exist.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now, i have changed `rawQuery` to `execSQL`

```
String update = "UPDATE ITEMS SET FOUND = 'YES' WHERE ITEM_NAME =" + "'"+click+"'";
            shoppingListDB.execSQL(update);
```